# Как из сторонней папки загружать Sprite в Image Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как мне похожим образом загружать Sprite не из папки Resources а из сторонней папки имея путь к файлу

В этом случае я могу использовать `GetAudioClip()` и присвоить в `map[i].audioclip` соответственно:

```
public void GetAudioClip()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath + "/Maps/Music"+i+"/");
        Debug.Log(di);
        FileInfo[] UserFiles = di.GetFiles("*.ogg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        if (UserFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            www = new WWW(di + UserFiles[0].Name);
            map[i].audioclip = www.GetAudioClip(true, true, AudioType.OGGVORBIS); 
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь я не знаю что использовать я хочу в `map[i].background` это тип Sprite запихнуть файл jpg к которому у меня есть путь, как мне это сделать.

```
public void GetBackground()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath + "/Maps/Music" + i + "/");
        Debug.Log(di);
        FileInfo[] UserFiles = di.GetFiles("bg" + i + ".jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        if (UserFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            www = new WWW(di + UserFiles[0].Name);
            Debug.Log(www.GetType());
            map[i].background = ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/generating-sprites-dynamically-from-png-or-jpeg-files-in-c.343735/ покрутите ниже, там ответ от Freznosis, возможно то что вам нужно.

Comment: помогло спасибо

Comment: `Sprite` это вобщем-то не картинка, а набор настроек. Нужно создать текстуру из байт [Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html), а затем можно создать спрайт, указав параметры изображения [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html). И то и другое `UnityEngine.Object`, не привязанный к сцене, как какой ни будь `ScriptableObject`, которые нужно не забыть удалить `Destroy(obj)`, иначе будут висеть в памяти, а текстура имеет заметный вес.

Comment: Кстате [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) устарел, о чём написано в документации. Нужно использовать [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html),  [DownloadHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler.html) / [UploadHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UploadHandler.html).